# Selecting Categories using API in Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am developing a integration between a desktop application and Amazon MWS and need to be able to offer users a choice of categories to put the product they are listing into. My problem is that I can't find any way of programmatically getting the current categories from MWS using the API.

Additionally once I have a category reference to use I will need a way to the pull in and add the category specific XML child of ProductData (eg Home, Jewelry, Computers, etc) but they don't seem to be linked in any well defined way. For example, I can't say "*if the chosen category is reference nnnnn ask them to populate the Computers specific ProductData*", unless I write something myself to map them.

Has anyone else come across these problems and found a workable solution?

Any help appreciated...

I am currently exploring the option of limiting users to only selling products already listed on Amazon but still can't figure out how to pull in the correct category specific XML.
There are various product look-ups but they all seem to work from either my SKU (which will not yet be there) or Amazons ASIN (which I don't yet know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use amazon advertizement api  for this.

You have to create account on amazon affiliate programme.From that you have to get security credentials also .

After That go to BrowseNode Tree Page and download root categories list and save it to file or database.From there you get categoryname and their browseNodeId.

Then call BrowseNodeApi to get Child Categories for parent Category.

Please Follow This Link 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ProgrammingGuide.html

code for calling BrowseNodeApi
SignedRequestHelper helper =
                             new SignedRequestHelper(appConfig["AWSAccessKey"], appConfig["AWSSecretKey"], appConfig["endpoint"]);

```
    string url = helper.Sign("http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=BrowseNodeLookup&BrowseNodeId=" + value + "&AssociateTag=beginners00-00&Version=2011-08-01");
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    // Get response  
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
    }
```

and also download SignatureGenerator class HMAC

Comment: This answers one part of the question: How to programmatically get the browse nodes (instead of just downloading the Browse Tree Guide from Seller Central). The other half of the question however remains open: How to know which XML structure to use for a specific category of products.

Comment: for the parent nodes you have to download list.after then when you select one of the category from that you can use subcategory by calling browse node api.i had created a sample application for this .I will provide link for this by tomorrow.

Comment: I think this is a valid answer so thank you for that. Not sure why this is not part of the MWS api though. As for picking the correct category specific XML I will try querying existing listings for products using getMatchingProductForId and see if the resulting ProductGroup and/or ProductTypeName can be mapped to the correct XML.